# Node id inside views template?

Tags: nodes

How to get the $node->nid inside a views template where i'm printing cck fields? $node variable is availabli only in node.tpl.php.

Answer (score 2):

If using **fields** as the display type the data will not be readily available in the display or style output, **but can easily be gotten in the field tpl's by accessing the `$row` object** which has all of the original raw data from the database.

Click on `Theme: Information` when in Views (editing the view in question) and you'll see all of the template recommendations to use. You'll probably want to use a tpl file that involves both the view and field name, e.g. `view-view-field--[view_name]--field-[field_name].tpl.php`.

Once you've created this tpl file you can access the following variables:

- `$view`: The view object
- `$field`: The field handler object that can process the input
- `$row`: The raw SQL result that can be used
- `$output`: The processed output that will normally be used.

You could do something special in `<?php ?>` and then print it like normal. For example, this would print out a specific field from a node that's referenced in a node_reference field:

`Contents of view-view-field--blog--field-blog-parent.tpl.php:`

```
<?php
$a_referenced_node = node_load($row->{$field->field_alias});
if ($a_referenced_node) {
  print $a_referenced_node->field_some_other_field[0]['value'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How is you view configured?  With a normal **Node** view, you can just add **Node: Nid** as one of the fields and then it will be available in your fields template.

Comment: i am using fields view, not a node...